# Custom widget with widgetlist and data-dojo-attach-event on children

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dojo

I have a custom widget with a WidgetList inside it.
I need to call a function in my custom widget when checkboxes in the WidgetList are checked but it seems I'm out of it's scope here;

I'm in the scope of each list item: lang.hitch: scope["topCheck"] is null (scope="[Widget dojox.mvc.Templated, dojox_mvc_Templated_25]")

**Markup**:
I want to attach the change event of my checkbox to the topCheck function on my custom widget.

```
<div>
<script type="dojo/require">
    at: "dojox/mvc/at"
</script>
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/WidgetList"
data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin"
data-dojo-props="children: at(this, 'fModel')">
<script type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate">                
    <li>                    
        <input id="" type="checkbox" data-mvc-bindings="value: at('rel:', 'id'), checked: at('rel:', 'visible')" data-dojo-attach-event="change: topCheck" />
        <label data-mvc-bindings="innerHTML: at('rel:', 'id'), for: at('rel:', 'id')"></label>        
    </li>
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

**Custom widget js**:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/on",            
    "dojo/parser",            
    "dojox/mvc/StatefulArray",
    "dojox/mvc/at",            
    "dojox/mvc/WidgetList",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/Evented",            
    "dojox/mvc/parserExtension",
    "dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin"
], function (
declare, on, parser, StatefulArray, at, WidgetList, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Evented) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Evented], {

        templateString: template,
        constructor: function (args, srcNodeRef) {
            declare.safeMixin(this, args);
            this.fModel = new StatefulArray();
        },

        postCreate: function () {
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },        

        topCheck: function (e) {

        }
    });
});
```

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (and/or the person who volunteered to answer this question) may have figured it out already, but here’s the trick: The widget owning the template containing the check box is neither the widget list or the custom widget containing the widget list. Instead, it’s the widgets that widget list implicitly creates (child widgets).

You can use a class you’d like for those child widgets, by `data-mvc-child-type` ([ref](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/WidgetList.html)). By using a custom class there, you can call a method of a parent widget (e.g. the widget containing the widget list) that may achieve your goal. Here’s an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
        <script id="custom-widget-with-widgetlist-template" type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate">
            <div>
                <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/WidgetList"
                    data-dojo-props="children: at(this, 'list')"
                    data-mvc-child-type="custom.Item">
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
        <script id="item-template" type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate">
            <li>
                <input id="${id}-check" type="checkbox" data-mvc-bindings="value: at('rel:', 'name'), checked: at('rel:', 'visible')" data-dojo-attach-event="change: checkboxChanged" />
                <label for="${id}-check" data-mvc-bindings="innerHTML: at('rel:', 'name')"></label>
            </li>
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: 1, parseOnLoad: 0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                "dojo/_base/declare",
                "dojo/parser",
                "dijit/registry",
                "dijit/_WidgetBase",
                "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
                "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
                "dojox/mvc/StatefulArray",
                "dojox/mvc/WidgetList",
                "dojox/mvc/parserExtension"
            ], function(declare, parser, registry, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, StatefulArray){
                declare("custom.Widget", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
                    templateString: document.getElementById("custom-widget-with-widgetlist-template").innerHTML,

                    constructor: function(args){
                        declare.safeMixin(this, args);
                        this.set("list", new StatefulArray([
                            {
                                name: "foo",
                                visible: true
                            },
                            {
                                name: "bar",
                                visible: false
                            }
                        ]));
                    },

                    checkboxChanged: function(){
                        console.log("Check box changed!");
                    }
                });

                declare("custom.Item", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
                    templateString: document.getElementById("item-template").innerHTML,

                    checkboxChanged: function(event){
                        // WidgetList's child instance -> WidgetList -> Custom widget containing WidgetList
                        registry.byNode(this.domNode.parentNode.parentNode).checkboxChanged(event);
                    }
                });

                parser.parse();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="dojo/require">
            at: "dojox/mvc/at"
        </script>
        <div data-dojo-type="custom.Widget"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I figured that out as mentioned in my question about scope. I solved it by having a nested custom widget for each widget list item - your solution looks awesome, it reduces the number of widgets that will be generated, since my solution will generate widget list item and a widget inside it, your solution will generate half the number of widgets, which is good :) I'm selecting your answer since it is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the checkbox to dijit.form.CheckBox or attach a dojo attach point to it.
Below is a sample code.

```js
postCreate: function () {
  this.inherited(arguments);
  console.log(this.testCheckBox);
  this.testCheckBox.onchange = this.topCheck; //Here this stands for the custom widget
},
```

```html
<input id="" type="checkbox" data-mvc-bindings="value: at('rel:', 'id'), checked: at('rel:', 'visible')" data-dojo-attach-point="testCheckBox" />
```

-Srikant

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, I'm looking for a more mvc'ish way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by creating another custom widget to hold each item in my widgetlist, added an attach-point to my checkbox and attached the event in the custom widget's postCreate.

This may look like the suggested answer above, the difference is that without the inner custom widget, the attach-point would belong to another widget;
this.someAttachpoint would not work because it would belong to a widget in the widgetlist, not my custom widget

I would have had to use registry.byId to get a hold of it.